# Unable to remove participant from further transaction on same asset

Tags: corda

**Parties in the business. .**
Parties A  , B , C

Asset : Order

Party A sends first transaction for both parties B and C

Party B sends next transaction to A and C (on same order , we used vault query to get input state)

Now we want Party C should not receive any future transaction on this Order. When we remove C from participant list we get following error. Looks like Corda is taking participant list from input state. Please suggest a solution to the problem.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants: [O=C, L=NV, C=US]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message comes from the `FinalityFlow`:
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/56067acd208b1b58f17cca85c0eb40ad0e9a1ff5/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L159-L161

To explain why you got that error, let's go back to the definition of `participants`:
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/56067acd208b1b58f17cca85c0eb40ad0e9a1ff5/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/contracts/ContractState.kt#L19

> A *participant* is any party that should be notified when the state is created or consumed.

Following that statement, when your transaction has one (or more) inputs and one (or more) outputs, then this transaction should be recorded (i.e. `finalized`) in the **union** of all `participants` of all input and output states, because again; following the `participants` definition, they should be notified when their states are created or consumed.

That's why, finality flow expects a `FlowSession` for each participant in the transaction, and throws the error that you saw when it finds a missing one.

Now, regarding privacy concerns (the other part of your question); even though `FinalityFlow` records the finalized transaction in the union of all participants; it doesn't record all outputs states in all vaults, it has a parameter called `StatesToRecord` which defaults to `ONLY_RELEVANT`:
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/56067acd208b1b58f17cca85c0eb40ad0e9a1ff5/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L47

Which means, a node will only register the states that it participates in.

So to summarize, the transaction will be recorded in the union of all participants (of all input/output states), but each participant will only register in their vault the relevant output states.

**Important:** The peer node that calls `ReceiveFinalityFlow` might override the default value of `statesToRecord` and choose `ALL_VISIBLE` which means record all output states of the transaction whether it's a participant or not:
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/56067acd208b1b58f17cca85c0eb40ad0e9a1ff5/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L272-L274

I suggest you read my article on privacy analysis using CDL here; it's more detailed about this topic: https://blog.b9lab.com/how-to-design-a-cordapp-and-analyze-privacy-leaks-using-cdl-views-da825953ff54

Comment: Thank you so much for giving much useful information. I am able to resolve my problem with your suggestion.